# Navigating through a matrix of booleans

Tags: java, arrays, loops, matrix, boolean

I've been trying to get more serious about learning Java, so I have been looking through the several hundred unread "Daily Coding Problems" in my inbox.  One of them is the following:

"You are given an M by N matrix consisting of booleans that represents a board. Each True boolean 
    represents a wall. Each False boolean represents a tile you can walk on.

Given this matrix, a start coordinate, and an end coordinate, return the minimum number of steps 
    required to reach the end coordinate from the start. If there is no possible path, then 
 return
null. You can move up, left, down, and right. You cannot move through walls. You cannot wrap
around the edges of the board."

For example, given the following board:

```
[
 0  1  2  3
0[f, f, f, f],
1[t, t, f, t],
2[f, f, f, f],
3[f, f, f, f]
]
```

"and start = (3, 0) (bottom left) and end = (0, 0) (top left), the minimum number of steps 
required to reach the end is 7, since we would need to go through (1, 2) because there is a 
wall everywhere else on the second row."

I tried using this code:

```
    boolean map[][] = {{false, false, false, false}, {true, true, false, true}, {false, false, false, false}, {false, false, false, false}};

    int xPos = 3;
    int yPos = 0;

    int xPosFinal = 2;
    int yPosFinal = 0;

    int steps = 0;

    //  Look up then look right then look down then look down then look left
    while (xPos != xPosFinal && yPos != yPosFinal) {
        if (!map[xPos - 1][yPos]) { //  Check up
            xPos -= 1;
            steps++;
        } else if (!map[xPos][yPos + 1]) {  //  Check right
            yPos += 1;
            steps++;
        } else if (!map[xPos + 1][yPos]) {  //  Check down
            xPos += 1;
            steps++;
        } else if (!map[xPos][yPos - 1]) {  //  Check left
            yPos -= 1;
            steps++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Getting through this maze requires " + steps + " steps to complete.");
```

When I try to run it however, the number of steps is not updated.  I did a little research and found something about the Lee Algorithm, but this is listed as an easy problem and most likely doesn't require anything too advanced to solve.  I just have much to learn about Java.'

Let me know what you think.  Any help is much appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: It is probably listed as easy, since there are many articles showing "shortest path" algorithms, e.g. [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm#Algorithm) or the [A* search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Example). --- Your code doesn't work because you don't backtrack if you walk the wrong way, you don't prevent walking where you've already been, and you don't try all possible directions from a given point, which would require recursion or a queue.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you, I will look into some of those algorithms and refactor my code